# Google Cloud deployment using huge amounts of reads

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, deployment, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function with about 24 functions. Functions are hooked to Firebase Firestore (they do read/write operations in collections/documents in it).

If I deploy all 24 at once I see in the google cloud platform monitoring a huge spike (about 5.5k reads in the 3 minutes that it takes to deploy all the functions).

Does anyone know or can explain why this is the case? During this time, nobody else is reading/writing into the firestore. Please see attached screenshot for the chart.

[image]

Comment: What's this chart? The read in firestore? Or the external request traffic (read external sources)?

Comment: Could you include more information about the nature of said functions? Such as the type of function, are they cron jobs? Are they just firestore triggers? What are the documents they read?

Comment: The chart is the # of reads. As you can see it spiked a lot

Comment: The information of the functions are these: a bunch of functions where it takes in a call to the function, reads off the provided auth token, and writes/reads to the firestore. They can be complex, hitting multiple docs/collections in one go. There are also a few functions that are cron jobs including one that runs every 15 min, and one that runs every hour.

Comment: Hi @lawonga you mentioned that during the deploy, no writes or reads are performed in your database. However, these functions seems to be writting/reading and you even confirmed that in your last comment. Have you tried to deploy them individually so you can check which of them might be causing this issue? Or even if you deploy just one, you face the same number of requests?

Comment: Right - I'm not calling anything else on the database during the deployment, as it only lasts about three minutes. I'm also the only one working on this particular database so it's only me. I'll try deploying one and seeing.

Comment: Hi @lawonga any news regarding the tests?

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me. Forgot about it so I just ran quick test just now. Deployed one function, it did 251 reads over a 2 minute time frame. See attached screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/HxIewnd . Let me know what you think! Thanks

Comment: Hi @lawonga it seems that indeed your functions are causing a lot of reads, as just one caused more than 250, if you multiply this by more than 20, the value will be around your 5k. You will probably need to change your functions, in case you want to lower your number of reads. There isn't much option.

Comment: So this is during function deployment, and not actually executing the functions. Is it safe to say that deploying a cloud function leads to reads? Curious because I don't think this is written in the documentation. Regular function usage is fine, and doesn't lead to excessive reads. Just the act of deploying does.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! It seems that contacting Google's 1:1 Support would be the best option for you, so they can access your environment and further check. You can contact them [here](https://cloud.google.com/support).